# FXG file looks ok in AI and Flash CS, but wrong in Flex app produced by FB - out of bound lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-flash

In a Flex card game I have all cards as vectors (purchased as stock cliparts), but the back of the cards has been bitmap (couldn't find a good stock clipart)

So I've asked a designer at a job board to draw me a back in Adobe Illustrator, which she did and the FXG file looks flawlessly -

in Adobe Illustrator:

[image]

and in Flash CS6:

[image]

But looks absolutely wrong where I need it - in Flash Builder:

[image]

Does anybody please know, how to get rid of those "out of bounds" lines?

How to "cut" them of? This is porbably some minor change, but I just can't find it in AI.

**UPDATE:** On Scott's suggestion (thanks!) I have selected **Expand Apperance**:

[image]

But can't find the *crop* he suggests...

Comment: You can't go back to the original creator? Essentially you need to Expand the Appearance, then Pathfinder > Crop in Illustrator. It's difficult to provide steps beyond that without actually seeing a sample file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Illustrator.....

Rearrange the layer stack so it looks like this:

[image: layers]

Basically move that `<Clipping Path>` above the `<Group>` inside the `<Clip Group>`

Now select the `<Clip Group>` by clicking the little circle to the right of the layer. You should see it highlight with blue squares the same as the image above.

Now click the Crop button on the pathfinder Panel (Window > Pathfinder)

[image: pathfinder]

Save and close, or do whatever. The extended objects should be removed now.

[image: Final]

The layer stack had to be reordered because the Crop command uses the topmost object in a stack to crop. Therefore the clipping path had to be moved above all the objects it was masking in order to crop correctly.

Expanding artwork was not necessary for this image. As I commented, it was a guess before seeing the actual file :)

Comment: Awesome explanation, the cropping has worked flawlessly. However the FXG file seems unoptimized and slows down the whole program... Is offtopic though